# why does a missing optional parameter cause an "Incompatible types" error

Tags: delphi, generics, optional-parameters, type-constraints

Can someone please explain why I get an "Incompatible type" error (Delphi XE3) in the following program (see comments at the bottom of the code for details) when I omit an optional parameter for the constructor?

```
program Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

type
  BaseClass = class(TObject);

  ChildClass = class(BaseClass);

  GenericBaseClass<T> = class
  public
    constructor Create(Fixed: Integer);
  end;

  GenericClass<T: BaseClass> = class(GenericBaseClass<T>)
  public
    type
      TMyProc = procedure (DataObject: T) of object;
  public
    constructor Create(Fixed: String; Optional: TMyProc = nil);
  end;

constructor GenericClass<T>.Create(Fixed: String; Optional: TMyProc);
begin
  inherited Create(12);
end;

constructor GenericBaseClass<T>.Create(Fixed: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create();
end;

var
  Gc: GenericClass<ChildClass>;

begin
  // this call is okay
  Gc := GenericClass<ChildClass>.Create('', nil);
  // this call fails: E2010 Incompatible types: 'ChildClass' and 'T'
  Gc := GenericClass<ChildClass>.Create('');
end.
```

Comment: The error message suggests to me that the instantiation of generic types doesn't work for default arguments, that the default argument of `GenericClass<ChildClass>` remains a constant `nil` of type `GenericClass<T>.TMyProc`, rather than the intended constant `nil` of type `GenericClass<ChildClass>.TMyProc`. Can you check that, by testing whether default arguments of non-dependent types do work?

Comment: non-dependant types seem to work (e.g. when I change the type of the `Optional` parameter from `TMyProc` to `Pointer`, it works)
your explanation sounds reasonable, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `reintroduce` or `overload` to the `GenericClass` constructor since you have multiple constructors with the same name but different parameters.

Comment: The way I am reading the question, hiding the base class constructor is intentional, so `overload` would be wrong. And `reintroduce` should not have any effect other than suppressing a warning for the class declaration, should it?